# ngrepeat checkbox in table rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

Good day everyone. I was hoping someone can help me with my Angular JS code. I have an image

[image]

which was populated based on this array of objects.

```
[
  {
    "groupName": "Group 1",
    "devices": [
      {
        "deviceId": "1111",
        "modelName": "Model 1",
        "baseModelName": "base1",
        "serialNumber": "ZZZZZZZZZZZ",
        "ipAddress": "10.191.21.50",
        "description": "Device 1"
      },
      {
        "deviceId": "2222",
        "modelName": "Model 2",
        "baseModelName": "base2",
        "serialNumber": "YYYYYYYY",
        "ipAddress": "10.191.21.168",
        "description": "Device 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Group 2",
    "devices": [
      {
        "deviceId": "333",
        "modelName": "Model 3",
        "baseModelName": "base3",
        "serialNumber": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "ipAddress": "10.191.21.124",
        "description": "Device 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me in coding my angularjs javascript controller so that I can only check/uncheck the checkbox under the selected group(the radio button).
Thank You.

Comment: please reformat your question and add a bit more information on what you did/what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide use your code

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before post question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-disabled` on the checkbox which can have the expression
 `"vm.selectedGroup !== 'Group 1'"` or
`"vm.selectedGroup !== group.name"` assuming you have a `ng-repeat` which the element is called `group`

You can also have some logic to uncheck the checkboxes when the `selectedGroup` changes.